# C++ iterator not derefancable

Tags: c++

i am new in c++ and i try to make The Bunny exercise but i have some problems with my code , please take a look at this code:
the error is vector iterator not dereferancable // and // standard library is out of range.
Thanks for helping me !

```
void  GameUpdate()
{   
vector<Iepuras>::iterator it;
vector<Iepuras>::iterator i;
bool ExistaTata=false; // dad exist
    i = Lista.begin();
while (!ExistaTata && i != Lista.end()) // dad exist

    if (i->Varsta >2 && i->Sex == "Male")
    {
        ExistaTata = true; //dad exist
        i++;
    }
else 
{
    i++;
}
for (it = Lista.begin(); it != Lista.end();it++)
{
    it->Varsta++;  // age ++ 
    it->title = it->Sex + " " + it->Nume + " "+ it->Color + " " + to_string(static_cast<long long>(it->Varsta));
    if (it->Varsta >2 && it->Sex == "Female")  // if age > 2 and female
        if (ExistaTata)   // if dad exist
        {  // new bunny
            Iepuras *f;
            f = new Iepuras;
            Lista.push_back(*f);
        }
    while (it->Varsta>10) // if age > 10 erase bunny
    {
        it = Lista.erase(it);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a method via a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833257/how-to-call-a-method-via-a-vector)

Comment: You don't need `new` to create new "bunnies" (it causes a memory leak in your case), just write `List.push_back(Iepuras())` or `Iepuras f; Lista.push_back(f);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason of the problem is the following loop

```
while (it->Varsta>10) // if age > 10 erase bunny
{
    it = Lista.erase(it);

}
```

After this loop it can be equal to Lista.end() (and in the condition of this loop where you are trying to access a data member) which you then are increasing in the enclosing loop

```
for (it = Lista.begin(); it != Lista.end();it++)
```

Also maybe I am mistaken but I do not see where iterator i is used after the first loop. So I do not see any sense in declaration of the iterator outside the loop.

Take into account that there is a memory leak due to these statements

```
    if (ExistaTata)   // if dad exist
    {  // new bunny
        Iepuras *f;
        f = new Iepuras;
        Lista.push_back(*f);
    }
```

because a copy of object *f will be placed in the vector.  Thus object *f is allocated but not deleted. You could write simply

```
        Lista.push_back( Iepuras() );
```

ALso instead of this dance with tambourine

```
bool ExistaTata=false; // dad exist
    i = Lista.begin();
while (!ExistaTata && i != Lista.end()) // dad exist

    if (i->Varsta >2 && i->Sex == "Male")
    {
        ExistaTata = true; //dad exist
        i++;
    }
else 
{
    i++;
}
```

I would suggest to use standard algorithm `std::any_of` declared in header `<algorithm>` In this case your code would be more clear.
I think you should rewrite the function entirely.

Comment: thank's you very much , i will rewrite the function listen at your advice .